# Is it possible to combine the two MiniProfiler results for an IIS Default Document request?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, mvc-mini-profiler

I have MiniProfiler setup in an ASP.NET website on IIS 7.5, and the Default Document is set as `Default.aspx`.

If I browse to `http://localhost/Default.aspx` directly only one result is correctly shown.

When I browse to `http://localhost/` two MiniProfiler results are displayed as shown in the screenshots below. The first result is actually for the previous request (note the timestamps are 25 seconds apart). The second result is for this request, but it doesn't appear to be the complete picture as if I refresh the page, the response includes another result similar to the first one pictured, but with the same timestamp as the original request.

Is there any way to show the MiniProfiler results for a request in a single set of results, and on the correct response when using Default Documents in IIS?

[image: First result]
[image: Second result]

Comment: does the first do a redirect?

Comment: Fiddler confirms that it is a straightforward request and 200 OK response, no redirect.

Comment: Possibly doing a transfer, then. It looks like this hits the ASP.NET pipe twice, so I don't *think* I can do much about it; how much of a problem is it causing, currently? I can *try* to detect whether it is a transfer, but it would take some digging...

Comment: I can work around it by not using the implicit Default Document URL. I believe you are right that it's a transfer. Application_BeginRequest () is fired twice.

Comment: there are some possibilities - for example [see here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2009/07/13/detecting-server-transfer.aspx?Redirected=true) - however, I strongly suspect it will be very hard to try to retrieve the old values. In some ways, it has presented you a very honest and revealing look at what ASP.NET has done under the covers. I'm almost tempted to declare this a free bonus feature!

Comment: In practice the most pertinent information is shown on the correct response so I'm not too concerned now I see what is happening. I agree about the bonus feature, although it would be even better if both profiler results were rendered on the correct response.